# RabbitMQ sharded queues with one consumer

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, sharding

Is it possible to have one consumer consuming from all the sharded queues in an exchange? With the following code I am only consuming from one of the queues:

```
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                channel.QueueDeclarePassive("TestExchange");
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "TestExchange",
                                     autoAck: true,
                                     consumer: consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need one consumer per queue.